# InvalidKeyException using ECPublicKey

Tags: encryption, cryptography, java

I'm getting the following exception when i try to encrypt a byte array with a EC public key :

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key:
sun.security.ec.ECPublicKeyImpl
```

This exception is generated when i call Cipher.init(). The lines below show what I did in my program:

```
ECPublicKey publicKey ;
ECPrivateKey privateKey;

//Generating key paire (public and private keys) 
    KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", "SunEC");
    SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");

    keyGen.initialize(571, random);
    KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
    privateKey = (ECPrivateKey) pair.getPrivate();
    publicKey = (ECPublicKey) pair.getPublic();

// get an AES cipher object with CTR encription mode 
   Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");

// encrypt the sharedSecret using the public key
   cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);**
   byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(data);
```

Must I add a provider to support this public key ??

Comment: You are trying to use the AES algorithm with an ECC key. To use AES (directly, not hybrid of password-based etc.) you need to use an AES key, not any kind of ECC key. To encrypt with an ECC key, you need to use an *algorithm* which uses an ECC key. Standard Sun/Oracle JCE does not have any encryption algorithm for ECC, only signature (ECDSA) and keyagreement (ECDH). BouncyCastle apparently supports ECIES, which does hybrid ECC/symmetric encryption, but I haven't tried it myself. If you use BouncyCastle through JCA, you need to add it as a provider.

Comment: Thank you @dave_thompson_085. I'm using ECC key because i use ECDSA for signature. I will try BouncyCastle and I will give you the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the source of this exception. The problem was initialization of cipher :

```
//This is the wrong initialization
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");

//This is the right initialization
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding","SunJCE");
```

But now, i have another exception which is (it is less important than the previous one) :

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 170 bytes
```

So what must I use as encrypting algorithm with ECDSA public key now ?